# Land cover data for British Columbia, Canada

Tags: data, remote-sensing, landsat, land-cover, canada

I am hoping to map vegetated (trees and open veg) for the lower mainland in BC, Canada.

I guess what I want is a Land Cover map.

Does this exist for download anywhere or will I need to user Landsat to create an NDVI and do it myself.

~30m resolution is adequate. Currency is not a huge issue.

Comment: Have you tried searching the DataBC Catalogue (http://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/)?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your end goal, you might have luck with the [Vegetation Resource Index polygon](http://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset/vri-forest-vegetation-composite-polygons-and-rank-1-layer) layer available from the [DataBC Catalogue](http://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/).

The VRI is:

> Geospatial **forest inventory dataset** updated for depletions, such as harvesting, and projected annually for growth. Sample attributes in this dataset include: age, species, volume, height.
>
> The Vegetation Resources Inventory (VRI) determines both where a resource is located and how much of a given vegetation resource (for example, timber or coarse woody debris) is within an inventory unit.

So, it's a land cover map that focuses on vegetation, but also provides a lot of extra attribute information.

Comment: unfortunately not, this classifies all of the lower mainland as U for urban. even parks and reserves. I think this one is good for non-urban regions only. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The tree cover for your region in 30m spatial resolution can be extracted from Hansens [*Global Forest Change Dataset*](http://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest/download_v1.2.html).

There is also a [publication](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/342/6160/850) acompanying the results, as well as a  [Google Maps based visualization](http://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest).

Answer (score 0):

This [map of North American land cover](http://www.cec.org/tools-and-resources/map-files/land-cover-2010-landsat-30m) at a spatial resolution of 30 meters provides a harmonized view of the physical cover of Earth's surface across the continent based on 2010 Landsat satellite imagery.

Answer (score 0):

[Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) is a public domain map dataset available at a couple scales.

I've never run into any quality issues from NED and have used it for a lot of different projects. They have a land coverage map under Raster.